# How to open request in default browser for onCreateWindow in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, browser, webview, window

I am working on Android/Kotlin `WebView`. I have set,

```
 webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient(mContext)
 webView.webChromeClient = MyWebViewChromeClient(mContext)

val settings = webView.settings
    settings.userAgentString = "App Agent"
    settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
```

Now, when a new window request comes from web app,currently it's opening the new window with apps `webView` like,

```
class MyWebViewChromeClient(private val mContext: BaseActivity): WebChromeClient() {

    override fun onCreateWindow(view: WebView?, isDialog: Boolean, isUserGesture: Boolean, resultMsg: Message?): Boolean {

        val window = WebView(mContext)
        // set settings
        val parent: RelativeLayout? = mContext.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.mainLayout)
        parent?.removeAllViews()
        parent?.addView(window)

        val transport = resultMsg?.obj as WebView.WebViewTransport
        transport.webView = window
        resultMsg.sendToTarget()

        return true
    }
}
```

So, how can I open a new window request with Android default browser?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @RahulKhurana my expectation is all links should be open with apps webview but if its a request for new window then the request should be handled by external default browser i.e. chrome browser.

Comment: In **onCreateWindow** you should make an Intent to open browser

Comment: Could you elaborate in answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the **onCreateWindow** method obtain the URL of the link from below code:

**Working solution**

```
override fun onCreateWindow(view: WebView?, isDialog: Boolean, isUserGesture: Boolean, resultMsg: Message?): Boolean {
    mContext.runOnUiThread {
        try {
            // here `url` parameter is the caller url
            mContext.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(view.url))))
        }catch (e: Exception){
            EmrLogger.e(classTag, e)
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

**mContext** is the context on which the `webView` is created.

**EDIT**

```
WebView newWebView = new WebView(getContext());
newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
            Bitmap favicon) {
         // Here param `url` is the target url
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
});
WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
transport.setWebView(newWebView);
resultMsg.sendToTarget()
```

Answer (score 0):

Folowing Rahuls answer I found a way that can be much faster, you just have to turn off network loads so the webview really doesn't load but gives you the target (if you want the last redirected target just leave the loads on).
This helped me so I thought it might help others too.

```
WebView newWebView = new WebView(myActivity);
                newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                                              Bitmap favicon) {
                        // Here param `url` is the target url

                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                        view.destroy();
                    }
                });
                newWebView.setNetworkAvailable(false);
                newWebView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(true);
                WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
                transport.setWebView(newWebView);
                resultMsg.sendToTarget();
```